QGIS Cloud login problem
I tried to publish my map(layer) on the WEB based on the QGIS Cloud plugin describition. I am loged in by using my user name and password. However I could not go further because of this erorr message.
================================================
An error has occurred while executing Python code:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'cursor'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users/tasaz0604/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qgiscloud\qgiscloudplugindialog.py", line 427, in check_login
self.refresh_databases()
File "C:\Users/tasaz0604/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qgiscloud\qgiscloudplugindialog.py", line 653, in refresh_databases
db_size = self.db_size_name(name)
File "C:\Users/tasaz0604/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qgiscloud\qgiscloudplugindialog.py", line 1539, in db_size_name
cursor = conn.cursor()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'cursor'
Python version: 3.9.18 (heads/master:5eba59e, Feb  1 2024, 20:02:10) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]
QGIS version: 3.34.5-Prizren Prizren, 4b308492
Python Path:
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS33~1.5/apps/qgis-ltr/./python
C:/Users/tasaz0604/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
C:/Users/tasaz0604/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS33~1.5/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS33~1.5\apps\grass\grass83\etc\python
C:\Users\tasaz0604\Documents
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.34.5\bin\python39.zip
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS33~1.5\apps\Python39\DLLs
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS33~1.5\apps\Python39\lib
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.34.5\bin
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS33~1.5\apps\Python39
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS33~1.5\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS33~1.5\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\win32
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS33~1.5\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS33~1.5\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
C:/Users/tasaz0604/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
C:\Users\tasaz0604\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins
D:/Min disk/QGIS
===============
QGIS version
3.34.5-Prizren
QGIS code revision
4b308492
Qt version
5.15.3
Python version
3.9.18
GDAL/OGR version
3.8.4
PROJ version
9.3.1
EPSG Registry database version
v10.098 (2023-11-24)
GEOS version
3.12.1-CAPI-1.18.1
SQLite version
3.41.1
PDAL version
2.6.0
PostgreSQL client version
16.2
SpatiaLite version
5.1.0
QWT version
6.1.6
QScintilla2 version
2.13.4
OS version
Windows 10 Version 2009
Active Python plugins
crayfish
3.6.0
processing_saga_nextgen
1.0.0
profiletool
4.2.6
QCopycanvas
0.7
qgis2web
3.19.0
valuetool
3.0.19
db_manager
0.1.20
grassprovider
2.12.99
MetaSearch
0.3.6
otbprovider
2.12.99
processing
2.12.99
qgiscloud
3.9.9
qwc2_tools
v1.1.0

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Thank you @Community I tried to publish my map(layer) on the WEB based on the QGIS Cloud plugin describition. I am loged in by using my user name and password. However I could not go further because of this erorr message.

The message is unfortunately not entirely clear, but it means that the database is full and an upgrade to QGIS Cloud Pro or more storage space is required.
